# Possible to include machine specs on community profile?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Just wondering if it's possible to add basic specifications on a users community profile page that specify some of the following characteristics:

- Machine Manufacturer
- Machine Model
- Preferred Slicing software

Then, a flair-like control can be added to any questions that they ask?

I typed in a quick example of how it might look with our current flair:

[image]

Here's a snippet of the HTML, I just placed it under the `<div class="user-details"></div>` control in the flair control:

```
<div>
  Runs a <span id="user-Manufacturer">MakerBot</span> <span id="user-Model">Replicator Dual</span> using <span id="user-Slicer">MakerWare</span>
</div>
```

Just a thought for a potential mod here in the community.

**Side note:** The same concept could be applied to other sites as well. Ie, StackOverflow could have preferred language(s) and/or IDE(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

99.9% sure this will be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Issue is, we try to keep the UI clean. If you are truly interested in this, then you can look at the user's profile page. If you want to see what they are knowledgeable in, look at the top tags in their profile.  It just adds to much clutter to posts.